# Laravel 5.5 RedirectTo not working in LoginController

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.5

I need your help.

When a user login I need to direct them one multi language router  and from what I've read I simply add RedirectTo in my LoginController, but doing so has no effect:

```
class LoginController extends Controller
{
.
.
     //protected $redirectTo ='/Utilisateur';(it's working)
     protected $redirectTo =  route('displayNew');(it isn't working)
.
.
}
```

INFO : In fact, on Laravel after the login, the user is redirected to home (redirection by default), to change this behavior, we must give a value to the `redirectTo` variable. The function that treats this variable is:

```
trait RedirectsUsers{ 
public function redirectPath(){
   if (method_exists($this, 'redirectTo')) {
        return $this->redirectTo();
    }

    return property_exists($this, 'redirectTo') ? $this->redirectTo : '/home';
}
}
```

Comment: Class variables has to be a static value. You can't do evaluations there. You can do it in the constructor instead.

Comment: you're right, but when I boot into the constructor I have the following error "Access to undeclared static property: App \ Http \ Controllers \ Auth \ LoginController :: $ redirectTo"
So you're right about " Class variables has to be a static value " but how do I do that for dynamic - @aynber

Comment: Not that kind of static value. `protected $redirectTo;` is fine, then assign the value in the `__construct()` method.

Comment: it does not work in constructeur:  `____construct(){ .. self::$redirectTo = route('displayNew')  ... }` .I have the same mistake before ( `Access to undeclared static property:...`) - @aynber

Comment: Hold on, adding an answer. I was trying to find a duplicate, but I'm not using the right search terms this morning.

Answer (score 3):

[Class properties](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php) has to be a "static" value on creation, ie a set value. You cannot use another PHP function to assign a value in the declaration, . You can get around it by setting the value in the constructor:

```
class LoginController extends Controller
{
     protected $redirectTo = '';

     public function __construct() {
         $this->redirectTo = route('displayNew');
     }

}
```

Comment: the code below bypasses the error, ie the error is no longer displayed but the redirection does not take place in the path I want

Comment: Where does it redirect to, and how are you using the redirect? Does the named route exist?

Comment: I modified the question

Comment: You may need to do some logging before the redirect. `Log::info(property_exists($this, 'redirectTo')); Log::info($this->redirectTo); Log::info(get_class($this));` Make sure that it's doing what you think.

Comment: Okay i'm using laravel 5.7.* and that's working for me, Thx for help

Answer (score 2):

If you need more robust customization of the response returned when a user is authenticated, Laravel provides an empty `authenticated(Request $request, $user)` method that may be overwritten if desired:

put this method in `LoginController.php`

```
protected function authenticated(Request $request, $user)
{
        return redirect()->route('displayNew');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have run `php artisan auth`

change the RedirectIfAuthenticated Middleware like so

```
class RedirectIfAuthenticated
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @param  string|null  $guard
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
    {
        if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {

            return route('displayNew');//change the redirect here
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

And in your route file you can do like so

```
Route::get('displayNew', 'MultiLanguageController@index')->name('displayNew');
```